# How to define implementation of function that combine call and construct signatures in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

The typescript documentation talks about function combine call and construct signatures。and describes how you can declare the type。https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html

```
interface CallOrConstruct {
  new (s: string): Date;
  (n?: number): number;
}
```

But it never shows how to define the actual implementation of such functions。 my english's not good, so I make a sample to descript my question, I will appreciate your answer。

```
interface CallOrConstruct {
    new (s: string): { s: string }
    (n: number): number
}
function invokeF (fn: CallOrConstruct) {
    fn(5)
    new fn('hello world')
}

var fn:CallOrConstruct  // how to define the actual implementation of fn
```

I want to know how to define the actual implementation of the type that combine call and construct signature。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) to distinguish between the calls. But you'll basically have to implement an overloaded function which requires liberal use of `any` to get it compile as TypeScript:

```
const fn = function(this: any, x: any): any {
  if (new.target) {
    // we're in a constructor now
    this.s = x;
  } else {
    // a plain function call
    return x;
  }
} as CallOrConstruct;
```

Comment: It does work, but it looks weird.  It still worked even i change the return like that **this.s = Number(x)** and** return String(x)**. That does not corresponding with the CallOrConstruct. It seems like the implementation does not care about the type rules.

Comment: Yes, `function(this: any, x: any): any` clearly does not care about the type rules. So: don't do that. But if you have such a function (typically defined in JS code), and you need to type it, combining call and construct signatures in the way shown in the handbook is the way to go.